# Alamofire request keeps coming nil

Tags: swift2, alamofire

So I am testing my code to see if i get connection with my php service, but I am still getting nil with this simple code:

```
<?php
 $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5); 
 echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The php output is: {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

but when I try it in the app, xcode console shows nil as result.

My alamofire request is:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET,url).responseJSON{ _,_, result in
 print(result.value)
}
```

I had to override Info.plist because the server I am using is http instead of https with the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>primefitness.hostoi.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I am new to swift, and I got no idea on how to debug or track the request. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I changed "mysite" to the actual site, to avoid confusions

Comment: The php content is live, actually in the site hostoi.com

Comment: well, "mysite" has to be change to the actual subdomain, primefitness.hostoi.com/scripts/pruebaios.php, in case you want to try it youself

Comment: Actual result is : `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->` Check it in browser. it should be clean json or xml so you can parse it.

Comment: the thing is, that the print in my swift code shows a nil result value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90434/discussion-between-inaki-pedroche-aramburu-and-iashish).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple, the hosting im using, uses an analitics javascript that was putting garbage to the end of my json, as stated by Ashish Kakkad, so i just disabled it.